# How to use ngSelect for JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

this is my json 
    [["A","aaa"],["B","bbb"],["C","ccc"]]
here the data 'aaa', 'bbb' and 'ccc' should be displayed in the dropdown 
when the data is selected their corresponding values ie 'A', 'B' or 'C' should be populated in the another variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<select ng-model="yourModel" 
        ng-options="val[0] as val[1] for val in testData">
</select>
```

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wgadj9vy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have this selector:

```
%select{"ng-model" => "recipeDifficulty", "ng-options" => "d.description for d in difficulties"}
```

And when I select one and click in a button, in my controller I add it to a JSON:

```
recipe = { ... 'difficulty_id': $scope.recipeDifficulty.id, ... }
```

I get the values from a db table with two fields: 'id' and 'description'